# Polar form of equation of line in $xy$-plane

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, polar-coordinates

Urgent help requested!! Anything I can do to get an answer faster, in terms of my question??

The question, diagram, and my work are attached. Any help or suggestions or hints are extremely welcome and appreciated.

[image: Homework help]

[image: image2]
My apologies for the tags. I couldn't find one that accurately described the content in this question. Also apologies for the bad title. Doing  this on a mobile device and I had too many  characters and then it made me wait for 30-60 seconds.

[image: more ideas]

More of my ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the shortest distance to the line from the origin is  $$r\cos(\theta - \theta_0) = r_0.$$  you can divide it out and get the polar equation of the line that is distance $r_0$ from the origin is $$r = \frac{r_0}{\cos (\theta- \theta_0)}.  $$

Comment: Call me stupid but I'm not understanding how $r cos($$\theta$ -$\theta_0$) = $r_0$

Comment: look at the right angle triangle in the figure with the hypotenuse $r$ and $r_0$ the perpendicular line from the origin to the line. the angle between the hypotenuse and this line is $\theta - \theta_0.$ use the formula $\cos = \frac{adj}{hyp}.$